# How to upgrade sqlite database from db file

Tags: android, sqlite, upgrade, android-sqlite

I have Android app that use SQLite database. I'd like to upgrade database from SQLite *.db file created from SQLServer using [this converter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26932/Convert-SQL-Server-DB-to-SQLite-DB). Any idea or example how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application/9109728#9109728